# Override cart controller twice or only override /checkout/cart/delete

Tags: controllers, overrides, onestepcheckout

In a shop using `Idev_OneStepCheckout` I need to override the deleteAction. OSC doesn't do this, but it does override `Mage_Checkout_CartController`, only for the `_goBack()` method. The shop also has a storeview that uses the standard OnePage checkout from Magento.

So, unfortunately, I can't do:

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
     <checkout>
       <args>
         <modules>
           <MyNameSpace_MyModule before="Idev_OneStepCheckout">MyNameSpace_MyModule_OneStepCheckout</MyNameSpace_MyModule>
           <MyNameSpace_MyModule before="Mage_Checkout">MyNameSpace_MyModule</MyNameSpace_MyModule>
         </modules>
       </args>
     </checkout>
   </routers>
 </frontend>
```

Well, I can, but my module isn't called in the OSC case. Disabling either makes it work for the checkout in question, so I know my code is correct.
Do I have to resort to a rewrite of `/checkout/cart/delete` for the onepage case or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow all your concerns, so apologies if this doesn't answer your question, but I'd approach this by

1. Creating a custom module
2. Adding a `<modules/>`/`before="Idev_OneStepCheckout"` "rewrite"
3. Have your new controller class extend the specific `Idev_OneStepCheckout` you're after

With the above in place you'll have the exact same functionality as you currently do, and then can replace whatever methods you want.

Instead of thinking of these as controller rewrites, it helps to think of them like this

> When a request for a URL that looks like  `/checkout/...` comes in, here's a list of module to look for controllers in

So you're not replacing controller files, you'll telling Magento "use my controller instead". Then, if your controller extends the older controller, you get the same behavior. A subtle different, but sometimes it helps people understand what's going on better.  The `Idev` folks did this for their module — if you do it for yours and tell Magento to check it first (i.e. the `before`) you should be set.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I did it. Guess I'll have to dig deeper why things don't work with the other store view. Thanks for confirming this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Alan, can you please put code with explain???